# Optimize EF query using Any instead of contains

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

That was my query with `Contains`:

```
db.NavFilters.Where(finalExpression)
  .Count(x => x.Attribute1 == e.Attribute && x.Link == link && x.SubLink == subLink && db.NavItemsFilters
  .Where(n=> !(n.Promo == string.Empty || n.Promo == null))
  .Select(n=>n.ItemID)
  .Contains(x.ItemID) )
```

But, as far as I know, contains is a hard operation, and I need to optimize it. Is such query will give the same result?

```
db.NavFilters.Where(x=> db.NavItemsFilters.Any(n=>n.Promo != string.Empty && n.ItemID == x.ItemID))
  .Where(finalExpression)
  .Count(x => x.Attribute1 == e.Attribute && x.Link == link && x.SubLink == subLink)
```

I know, that the best solution is to add navigation properties. But I can't do that for many reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can optimize you query like this:

```
var navFilters = db.NavFilters.Where(finalExpression);

var thereIsAny = (from x in navFilters
                  join n in db.NavItemsFilters on x.ItemID equals n.ItemID 
                  where n.Promo != string.Empty && x.Attribute1 == e.Attribute && x.Link == link && x.SubLink == subLink
                  ).Any();
```

Answer (score 1):

[IQueryable.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb338641(v=vs.90).aspx) does exist, so your query should get converted to SQL.

Comment: Iqueryable.contains is kind of a hack as there's no way to translate sql `in` with linq-to-sql/linq-to-entities. It just creates a whole lot of `or` statements, for large collections most of the time even goes to creating that query

Comment: @AlexanderDerck That's not true. What you are saying applies when the `Contains` is used on in memory collection. I fact when used on real EF queryable, both `Contains` and `Any` generate one and the same SQL with `EXISTS (subquery)` clause.

Comment: @IvanStoev hmm yeh just looked it up, I cant remember where I read that once... thanks for clearing that up though :)